# adding integer and to an hours value

Tags: c#, .net

I have a combobox which has values from 1-25.
I also have 2 datetimepickers which display time values.

If I choose `10:00 AM` for the first datetimepicker and `2` from the combobox, I'd like the result to be `12:00 PM` in the second datetimepicker.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
secondDatePicker.Value = firstDatePicker.Value.AddHours(Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue));
```

Comment: @Student Nope. it does not affect firstDatePicker's value. checkout [AddHours()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addhours.aspx) documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Simply look at MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx

Use the AddHours method.

Something like this :

```
int iIncrement = int.Parse(combobox.SelectedValue);
Datetime dt = firstDateTimePicker.value;
secondDateTimePicker.value = dt.AddHours(iIncrement );
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a form with two `DateTimePicker`s (dateTimePicker1 and DateTimePicker2) and one `ComboBox` containing the values specified, add an event handler to the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the combobox as follows:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the DateTime from the first picker
    var currentDateTime = dateTimePicker1.Value;
    // Get the number of Hours to add to the DateTime
    var hoursToAdd = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
    // Add the hours to the DateTim
    var newDateTime = currentDateTime.AddHours(hoursToAdd);
    // Tell dateTimePicker2 to use the DateTime that has the hours added
    dateTimePicker2.Value = newDateTime;
}
```